# A way to find answers to questions, by searching a given set of documents

Tags: search, full-text-search

As the title suggests, I am in need of finding / creating a system which is capable of retrieving relevant information for a query, by searching a set of given documents. From my own research, I have only found libraries who perform index based searching, that can point out which documents match the query, but they cannot extract relevant information. In short, a user will ask a question, and the system will try to find an answer to that question, by searching a given set of documents.

Can anyone point me towards a method of achieving this, or a library that might help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give custom advice to your use case these infos would be helpful:

- What type of documents: topics, style of writing;
- any priorities for programming language or OS?
- Should the result just show some context around the found text passage or phrase a correct answer sentence?

Generally this task seems to require tagging and semantic parsing of the texts. I like the nltk   http://www.nltk.org/ best.

Comment: The type of documents varies, it can be anything from scientific peppers to literature (though the latter will be more abundant). Preferred language is C#. No context is needed, just a simple answer.